# Sort posts by post_type in category.php template

Tags: categories

In my `category.php` template I want to sort category posts by their post types dynamic. My block must have this structure

```
Restaurant (custom post type)
 - posts 
Bars (custom post type)
 - posts 
Shops (custom post type)
 - posts
```

I need to know at first, in what post types are the posts of current category (something like this screenshot )

[image: screenshot]

This is a theme template, I don't want any custom queries for post, so maybe use some filter or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your query does indeed have multiple post types, you'll want to pluck them out before continuing (I assume you're using `$wp_query` as your WP_Query object):

```
<?php
$all_post_types = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->post_type;
}, $wp_query->posts);

// Now we get a unique list of post types:
$unique_post_types = array_unique($all_post_types);

// Use that unique list to drive multiple loops:
foreach($unique_post_types as $grouping) {
    // Build our "title" for each group, using esc_html to sanitize
    echo sprintf("<strong>%s</strong>", esc_html($grouping));

    //Start from the beginning of the list:
    rewind_posts();
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        if($post->post_type != $grouping) { // not a match for our current grouping?
            continue;
        }
        echo "<p>&ndash; " . get_the_title() . "</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

First I grab all post types from `$wp_query`, cull to a unique list, then use that to run the loop multiple times (once for each post type), wherein we only show posts for that type.  This is a rudimentary example, and won't give you the "friendly" names of your post types or the exact output you likely desire, but should give at least a skeletal framework around which to build your output.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` could just be `printf()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## **NOTICE**

Option one section one is done with the other answer in mind. Section one is interchangeable and can be used with the other answer or my approach in section 2 of option one. You can either use my approach here or the approach from @JustinBell. The important section here is section 1 which sorts your loop according to your predefined order according to post type first.

## **OPTION 1**

**SECTION 1**

This is the important section as this sorts the posts according to post type that is predefined by you

You can make use of `usort` to sort your posts using `the_posts` filter. 
The code make use of the following

- [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) -  Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function
- `the_posts` filter
- [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) - evaluates whether the current query (such as within the loop) is the main query
- [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) - checks if a category archive page is being displayed

The loop will be sorted first by post type, `restaurant`, then by post type `bars`, en then post type `shops`. The code will also keep posts in the same post type sorted by `post_date`

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts, $q ) {
    if( $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_category() ) {
        usort( $posts, function( $a, $b ){
            $post_types = array (
                'restaurant' => 1,
                'bars' => 2,
                'shops' => 3
            );

            $posts = $post_types[$a->post_type] - $post_types[$b->post_type];

            if ($posts === 0){
                //same post_type, compare by post_date.
                return $a->post_date < $b->post_date;
            }else{
                //different post_type, save to ignore the post_date.
                return $posts;
            }
        } );
    } 
    return $posts;  
}, 
10, 2 );
```

**SECTION 2**

This is your loop. As said before, the other answer's approach will also work perfectly here. Just to showcase another approach, I have done the following

Firstly create a new array called `$posts_reordered`. The post type names will be used as the array keys, and all posts with the same post type will be included under the respective key. This new array will be used to create the loop. This is how the loop looks like, this will go into your category.php. You just need to add your own html mark-up and modify as needed.

```
<?php

    $posts_reordered = [];
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $posts_reordered[$post->post_type][] = $post;
    }
    unset($post);

    foreach ( $posts_reordered as $key=>$value ) {
        echo '<ul>';

            echo $key;

            foreach ( $value as $post ) {
                setup_postdata($post); ?>

                <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </li>

            <?php }
            unset($post);
        echo '</ul>';

    }   

    // PLACE YOUR PAGINATION FUNCTION HERE

?>
```

This will render the following output (*`event_type`, `post`, and `cameras` are my post types I'm testing with and are in the ordered position I've set with the code in section one*)

[image]

## **OPTION 2**

<---SCRAPPED--->

The original code with `loop_start` did not bring the results that I was after, will maybe have a look at it again in the future, but I believe Option One to be the best as it is working as expected

Comment: Quite excessive editing here. Protip: Do _not_ name your variables `$p`. Name them what they are. +1 anyway. Using `the_posts` filter is the appropriate way to do that.

Comment: LOL, ja. Have been working on an idea and scrapped it halfway. Could not get it working. Thanks for the tip. Edited to correct accordingly